# Angular 5 with Cordova (Phonegap)

Tags: angular, cordova, phonegap

Setup: Create new angular project with `ng new mobile` and create build of that by `ng build`. Then create empty cordova project by `phonegap create mobile` and move the content of dist folder from angular into www folder of phonegap project, with add into index.html `<script src="cordova.js"></script>`
Issue: When I open the browser version of that app, everything works as it should, but when I open that application inside the phonegap app to test it, nothing shown. File `index.html` is opening normally but `<app-root></app-root>` is not filling with the page.
Logs on start app:

> [phonegap] starting app server...
>   [phonegap] listening on 192.168.0.102:8080
>   [phonegap]
>   [phonegap] ctrl-c to stop the server
>   [phonegap]

Logs on open page in browser:

> [phonegap] 200 /
>   [phonegap] 200 /cordova.js
>   [phonegap] 304 /socket.io/socket.io.js
>   [phonegap] 200 /styles.bundle.js
>   [phonegap] 200 /inline.bundle.js
>   [phonegap] 200 /main.bundle.js
>   [phonegap] 200 /polyfills.bundle.js
>   [phonegap] 200 /vendor.bundle.js
>   [phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8b8xS3
>   [phonegap] 200 /cordova_plugins.js
>   [phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8b8xSy&sid=20QHVka_YOvFssMwAAAA
>   [phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8b8xTY&sid=20QHVka_YOvFssMwAAAA

Logs on open page in phonegap app:

> [phonegap] [console.warn] Content Security Policy has been modified to be: https://ssl.gstatic.com > 'unsafe-eval' * ws:;style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: blob:;media-src *;img-src 'self' data: content: *;script-src * 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' data: blob:;">
>   [phonegap] 200 /**api**/appzip
>   [phonegap] 200 /socket.io/socket.io.js
>   [phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8b98u4
>   [phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8b98uZ&sid=ObEnma7oyhhUimWDAAAB
>   [phonegap] 200 /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=M8b98un&sid=ObEnma7oyhhUimWDAAAB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the base href=“/“ tag in your index.html to base href=“./”

Comment: Or even remove the tag